# Customising VSCode Auto Import Paths

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My directory structure looks something like this:

```
ingestion
  |__ src/
       |__ ion/
            |__ clients/
            |__ configurations/
                  |__ kafka.py
            |__ emitter/
                  |__ kafka_emitter.py
            |__ __init__.py
  |__ .pylintrc
  |__ pyproject.toml
  |__ setup.py
```

When performing auto import of `KafkaEmitterConfig` class from `configurations/kafka.py` in `kafka_emitter.py`, vscode resolves the auto import path to `ingestion.src.ion.configurations.kafka` instead of `ion.configurations.kafka` (setup.py is in `ion` not `ingestion`). How can I configure the auto imports to match the location of the setup.py as root?

Comment: Vscode uses the workspace as the root directory for file retrieval and import. If you want to get `ion.configurations.kafka`, you need to set the `src` as the workspace, which is obviously unreasonable。

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT is this shared with pylint? Linter also notes the imports as invalid